# White space at bottom on mobile, not reproducible in Chrome simulator

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I know there are various similar threads on this but none answer my question. Please look at this most simple HTML code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, blue, white);
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Viewed in Chrome for PC (either in normal view or in mobile simulator view) it produces a gradient background that covers the whole screen. Viewed in Firefox mobile for Android or Chrome mobile, the website has a white space at the bottom the size of the address-bar. It either appears right away or it appears when you attempt to scroll the page. Why is it there and how do I get rid of it?

[image: Firefox mobile]

Answer (score -1):

i had the same Problem till hours before.

Set body-height not 100vh, but 100%.
body,html{ padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; } (No background input here!)

In your html document you have to put in a new image-Tag('<'img id="image"'>')

At the end in CSS:

#image{ height: 100vh; background-image: url(..); z-index:-1; background-size: cover; }

So i found out, that 100% is smaller than 100vh actually, what actually kills the white bar at the bottom on android browser while scrolling out the navibar.
Sorry for my broken english. Greetings from germany. xD